# How to add escape $ in Zend framework query

Tags: php, sql, oracle, zend-framework, zend-db

I need to add `escape '$'` in zend framework.

**expected query:**

`SELECT * FROM V_HOME_SEARCH sv WHERE sv.NAME LIKE '%gar$_%' ESCAPE '$'`

**I tried this:**

```
public function selectData($str){
  $select = $this->select();
  $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
  $select->from(array('sv' => 'V_HOME_SEARCH'));
  $select->where('sv.NAME like (?)', '%'.strtolower($str).'%'); 
  $result = $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Here how can I add escape '$' in above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure that's not a valid [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement. If I'm wrong, can you link to the documentation for this `ESCAPE` clause because I can't find it anywhere

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for your command. Am using `Oracle` database https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Comment: Then why is this tagged [tag:mysql-real-escape-string]?

Comment: @Phil I don't know how it is tagged to  mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Can you not just include the `ESCAPE` clause in the `where()` call, ie `$select->where('sv.NAME like (?) ESCAPE \'$\'')`

Comment: Regarding tags, that's how you tagged the question. I've fixed it now but in future, please think about the tags you're using

Comment: @Phil wow its is working can you write you answer I will tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Db doesn't seem to offer any support for Oracle `LIKE` clauses with the `ESCAPE` keyword so all you can do is literally add it to the `where()` call

```php
$select->where("sv.NAME LIKE (?) ESCAPE '$'", '%' . strtolower($str) . '%');
```

Comment: @RameshS No worries. You might want to think about updating to a more recent library though. I'm pretty sure Zend is unmaintained and is now called [Laminas](https://getlaminas.org/)